# Does a freed memory set pointers referencing to it to null?

Tags: c, pointers, null

Imagine I have a struct for a linked list:

```
struct node{
     int data;
     struct node* next;
     struct node* prev;
};
```

I free the last node; does the `next` pointer of the node before it become `NULL` automatically?

Because I noticed I didn't do it in a program but everything runs fine..

Comment: Standard `free()` function don't set freed pointer to `NULL`. If *your* function to freeing have the setting feature, it may become `NULL` automatically.

Comment: @MikeCAT Other pointers to the same memory won’t, which is what OP is asking about.

Comment: No, the pointer and any other pointers to the `free`d memory become invalid (since it is no longer allocated memory). You must do the house-keeping yourself.

Comment: if is physically impossible as `free` takes only single pointer so it cannot be changed by this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

As for why your program appeared to run OK even if you forgot to reset a pointer, it could be you just got lucky.

Comment: I'd say it was ***un***lucky.  A prompt failure would have made the problem immediately apparent.  Instead, the "success" meant that there was a latent bug just waiting to cause a failure.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Your program got lucky by not crashing. You got unlucky by having your program crash when you demoed it to your boss instead of when you were writing it.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly shouldn't *rely* on any memory allocated by `malloc()` to get zero'd when you call `free()` on it. Certainly you shouldn't expect any pointers to that memory that exist elsewhere in your program to get zero'd.

It's worth running a program under `valgrind` or similar, to detect cases where a program works by a fortunate coincidence.

Comment: "...you shouldn't rely on any pointers to that memory that exist elsewhere in your program getting zero'd." It's worth noting that ***no*** pointers get zeroed by the `free` function, not even the pointer that is passed to `free()`.

Comment: Um, yes... that's why you shouldn't rely on it ;) But, yes, I realize that I've used "rely" in two different senses in the same answer. My bad.

Comment: Yes but phrasing it that way implies that it might happen sometimes, when the pointers are *never* reset, not even accidentally, by `free()`, except perhaps if the pointer is in the `free`d memory itself and is being illegally accessed by the program.

Comment: Alright, already -- I changed it. You want I should fall on my sword as well? ;)

Answer (score 1):

`void free(void *ptr);`

function prototype shows that it is not possible to set any value to the pointer
`ptr`.

So the the stored reference will be the same as before the call, but it will reference the invalid memory location. This kind of pointers are called `"dangling pointers"`. If you use this pointer it is an **Undefined Behaviour**.

Program invoking an UB may behave any way including the correct observable behaviour, but it is incorrect.

You need to make sure that you do not use dangling pointers.

Answer (score 0):

`free` can't zero its pointer argument in the caller because the pointer argument
is taken by value (copy).

```
void free(void *ptr);
```

You can't have a function that'd do it while remaining as generic as `free`, because `free` will free not just a pointer to void but any other pointer to a non-qualified type (=any other pointer that will implicitly convert to `void *`).

If you want such zeroing, for security or other reasons, while retaining `free`s genericity, you can wrap free in a macro.

Example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#define FREE(Pp) (free(*(Pp)),*(Pp)=NULL)
int main(void)
{
    char *m = malloc(1);
    if (!m) return 1;
    FREE(&m);
    assert(!m);
}
```